# Volley returns JSONException: Unterminated object at character

Tags: android, json, laravel, gson, laravel-passport

My app gets the error `JSONException: Unterminated character at ...` But it doesn't always give the error, although it is very frequent.

I'm not quite sure if it's the code or something related to network issue because sometimes it works really well, sometimes it doesn't, even if the data being sent from the server is the same as when it works, and when it doesn't.

My process is get a list of posts on the backend using laravel, with laravel-passport implemented with the API.

Below is the code on my laravel backend, but simplified:

```
$response['posts'] = Post::all();
return response()->json($response);
```

And on my android application, I read it with:

```
JSONArray jsonArrayPosts = response.getJSONArray("posts");
```

On all my network requests using volley, I have the following header:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("Accept", "application/json");
params.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + UserSingleton.getInstance().getUser().getAccess_token());
return params;
```

It works, but quite frequent, I get a network error on volley saying

`JSONException: Unterminated character at ...`

What could be the issue that I'm getting inconsistent results?

Comment: try using JSONArray jsonArrayPosts = response.getJSONObject("posts"); this should help I see that you are missing object

Comment: My code on android is fine, and it has to be JSONArray because I iterated on that data since I am displaying them using recycler view. My issue is that sometimes it returns a network error, sometimes it just works.

Comment: I still think your problem is something with JSON object it's invalid or something that's the reason for this error.

Comment: Have you solved this error? I am also experiencing it, your reply is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this flow,
1. Assign header authorization without Bearer word and a string value token.
2. Collect response in json object.
`JsonObject jO_One=new JsonObject(response);`
3. You need an json array object.
`JsonArray jA_One=jO_One.getJsonArray("ArrayName");`
4. Apply a loop for arrays data collection

```
    for(int i=0;i<jA_One.length;i++){  
        JsonObject jO_Two=new JsonObject(i);  
    // collect your values from keys
    int mobile=jO_Two.getInt("mobiles");  
    // now, you can store it into your  
 //arraylist or whatever you are using in here...   
    }
```

5. Done.